# react-native-tcp:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: react-native

Get an Error when I create a Signed APK.

> Task :react-native-tcp:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-tcp:verifyReleaseResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.
  >   Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  >   error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless
  >   .Colored not found.
  >   error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored no
  >   t found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v2
  >   6.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v2
  >   6.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v2
  >   6.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not fo
  >   und.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v2
  >   8.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v2
  >   8.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:27
  >   11: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:27
  >   12: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:27
  >   13: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:27
  >   14: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:27
  >   15: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:27
  >   96: error: resource android:attr/startX not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:27
  >   99: error: resource android:attr/startY not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:28
  >   02: error: resource android:attr/endX not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:28
  >   05: error: resource android:attr/endY not found.
  >   C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\reac
  >   t-native-tcp\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:28
  >   13: error: resource android:attr/offset not found.
  >   error: failed linking references.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 56s
55 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 52 up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use RN 0.55.4 and install "stream" and "stream-browserify" dependency by using npm and it would be work. it might work on last version of RN but i don't test it.
if you got error when create signed APK, use: `gradlew assembleRelease --console plain`

Comment: thank you for your solution. it works for me in RN 0.55.4. before that, I used RN 0.59.8 and not working.